# Small wrapper for easylist using \item like syntax and a new environment

Tags: environments, itemize, nesting, wrap, easylist

I'm trying to create a new environment for using the package `easylist` so that some users that are not used to `LaTeX` can easily make use of it. Right now the environment and its custom commands are defined like this:

```
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Style*=,Numbers=a,FinalMark={.})

\newenvironment{objectives}
{ 
    \newcommand{\spobj}{@}
    \newcommand{\goal}{@@}
    \newcommand{\ind}{@@@}
    \begin{easylist}
}
{
    \end{easylist}
}
```

This works:

```
\begin{objectives}
@ Objective 1
@@ Goal 1
@@@ Indicator 1
@@@ Indicator 2
@@@ Indicator 3
@@ Goal 2
@@@ Indicator 1
@@@ Indicator 2
\end{objectives}
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

I want to use the specific commands for adding the amount of `@` needed like this:

```
\begin{objectives}
    \spobj Objective 1
    \goal Goal 1
    \ind Indicator 1
    \ind Indicator 2
    \ind Indicator 3
    \goal Goal 2
    \ind Indicator 1
    \ind Indicator 2
\end{objectives}
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

I don't know the right way to achieve this. Maybe the problem is somewhere in between the time LaTeX translates the commands, or the command doesn't know it is inside a `easylist` environment.

Can someone tell me how to do this the right way? Maybe point me in the right direction..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to make `@` an active character with `\Activate` and switch off this feature with `\Deactivate` later on. This can be either done by using the `\spobj` etc. commands outside of `objectives` or wrap `\Activate\newenvironment{objectives}...\end{objectives}\Deactivate`

In addition, the `@` etc. characters must be followed by a space character (as stated in the documentation) in order to show the numbers/labels (which is most likely wanted for an enumeration)

In my point of view, `easylist` is a strange package, which nice features however, but difficult to understand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Style*=,Numbers=a,FinalMark={.})

\Activate
\newcommand{\spobj}{@ } % Explicit space after @ needed!!!!!
\newcommand{\goal}{@@ }
\newcommand{\ind}{@@@ }
\Deactivate

\newenvironment{objectives}
{%
  \begin{easylist}
  }
  {
  \end{easylist}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{objectives}
    \spobj Objective 1 

    \goal Goal 1

    \ind Indicator 1

    \ind Indicator 2

    \ind Indicator 3

    \goal Goal 2

    \ind Indicator 1

    \ind Indicator 2
\end{objectives}

\end{document}
```

[image]